# Формация и информация.

Tags: словообразование, однокоренные-слова

Формация – это структура, совокупность, общность…  в общем, нечто сформировавшееся, сформированное – приведённое к определённой форме. Меня интересует процесс образования слова «информация». Какие мнения на этот счёт у профессионалов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ФОРМА – слово известно с 15 века, от латинского forma – вид, наружность.

ФОРМАЦИЯ –  слово известно с 18 века, от латинского formatio – образование, формирование.

ИНФОРМАЦИЯ –  слово известно с 18 века, оно заимствовано через немецкий/французский язык  из латинского, от informatio –  изложение, истолкование, разъяснение. Таким образом, латинская приставка ИН обозначает ВВЕДЕНИЕ В ПОНИМАНИЕ  ФОРМЫ –  внешнего вида или внешнего выражения какого-либо содержания (философ.).